# E: unable to locate package spotify

Tags: command-line

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS alongside with my windows 11 on my laptop and its working pretty nice. I don't face any issue while installing/downloading packages/application through the terminal. bBut whenever I try to remove an application from the terminal, it gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: How do you install programs? What command did you use to install spotify?

Comment: in terminal type `snap list` to see if spotify is installed. If it is installed and you wish to remove it then in terminal use `sudo snap remove <package_name>`according to its description in snap list

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `type -a spotify`

Comment: Thanks!! The issue has been resolved.